# Add a wait between each forEach statement

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to add a wait time between each forEach statement in the below code, I don't want to run into problems with rate limits so I want to wait, say 1 second, between each time the forEach runs. Is this possible?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels of ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`); 
});


client.on("message", async message => {

  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
 
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  
  if(command === "addalltorole") {
     
    process.setMaxListeners(n);



     
    let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == 'TribeVerified')
     
    if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)

    var hasRoles = ["449032040147582977", "489252560532799488", "449032406444277760", "449032567988158465", "449032704122552320", "449032907332255759", "449033048374247426", "449033186413117441", "459119831183130645", "449033329946394645", "462285271505829909", "528059697257775106", "462061656852398090", "461635407893889037", "535632204026609665", "535632207222407168535637767242121216", "535637767242121216", "535637777388142593", "542049404270673942"];
     


     message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.filter(r => hasRoles.includes(r.id)).size > 2).forEach(member => member.addRole(role));


    message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role **${role.name}** was added to all applicable members`)

  }

});

client.login(config.token);
```

I found this on stackoverflow elsewhere, not sure if it could be of use to implement what I'm trying to do?

```js
var array = ['some', 'array', 'containing', 'words'];
var interval = 1000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
array.forEach(function (el, index) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(el);
  }, index * interval);
});
```

Thanks so much in advanced for any help!

Comment: Yes, the snippet you found elsewhere should apply here too. Instead of `.forEach(member => member.addRole(role))`, try `.forEach((member, index) => setTimeout(() => member.addRole(role), index * interval)))`. (Note this way of doing things over time isn't very flexible - you'd want to look into promises and potentially async/await for better control. That said, this probably isn't relevant to the program/bot you're creating.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that approach will work just fine.

It will space them 1 second apart regardless of how long they take to complete.

...and that's probably fine for what you are doing...

---

...but if you want you can use the fact that [`addRole`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) returns a `Promise` to do some cool stuff.

For example, this uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to pass along the `Promises` so that each call waits for the previous call to finish *and then* waits an additional second before making the next request:

```
message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.filter(r => hasRoles.includes(r.id)).size > 2)
  .reduce(async (previous, member) => {
    await previous;  // wait for the previous call to finish
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));  // wait another second
    return member.addRole(role);  // pass this Promise to the next iteration
  }, Promise.resolve());  // start with a resolved Promise
```

Here is a working demo you can run:

```js
class Member {
  constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
  async addRole(role) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));  // simulate asynchronous call
    console.log(`added role "${role}" to ${this.name}`);
  }
}

const members = [
  new Member('first'),
  new Member('second'),
  new Member('third'),
  new Member('fourth'),
  new Member('fifth')
];

members.reduce(async (previous, member) => {
  await previous;
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  return member.addRole('admin');
}, Promise.resolve());
```

...but yes, either approach will work and should be just fine for what you are doing.